# Simple question in number-theory

Tags: elementary-number-theory

$a, b, c$, and $d$ are integers. From exactly one of the equations $A, B, C, D, E$, one can deduce that $14$ divides $a \cdot b$. Which one?
A) $7a+8b=14c+28d$

B) $14a+28b=7c+8d$

C) $14a+8b=7c+28d$

D) $7a+28b=14c+8d$

E) $28a+8b=14c+7d$

I tried solving for $b$ in $x_1a+x_2b=x_3c+ x_4d$, then calculating $a\cdot b$ expressed by only $a$, hoping it would yield something. Otherwise I am clueless.

How can this be solved?

Comment: See if you can deduce, just from looking at the coefficients, whether $a$ is forced to be divisible by $2$ or $7$, and the same for $b$. Analogous example: in $9w+5x=15y+12z$, you can conclude that $x$ is a multiple of $3$. Do you see why?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: in $7a+8b=14c+28d$, what divisors can we say for sure that $a$ has, if any? What about $b$?